# Difference between cordova plugin and web API?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, cordova-plugins

I would like to know what is the difference between the Google Maps Cordova plugin and the web API of Google?

Thanks
YMonnier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin shows a native view that uses the Google Maps native SDK, the web API displays the map in the Cordova WebView same way as it works on any website.

The plugin should be more performant for displaying the map, specially for the gestures (moving the map, zooming, etc), but it's harder to integrate in the app as it's a native view. (this has improved over the years)

```
The oficial readme says:
How different between Google Maps JavaScript API v3?
This plugin displays the map view of native(Java and Objective-C) features, which is faster than Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

And the native map view works even if the device is offline.

This plugin provides the features of the native map view to JS developers.

You can write your code similar like the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.
```

The plugin also has support for offline maps and 3D View

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#how-different-between-google-maps-javascript-api-v3

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile